# XML and Hashtable

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, hashtable

I have the following XML file:

```
    <states>
      <state>
        <Name>a1</Name>
        <Address>a2</Address>
        <Name>b1</Name>
        <Address>b2</Address>
        <Name>c1</Name>
        <Address>c2</Address>
      </state>
      <state>
        <Name>aa1</Name>
        <Address>aa2</Address>
        <Name>bb1</Name>
        <Address>bb2</Address>
      </state>
    </states>
```

I need to store it in hashtable and retrieve values from it using C#.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Are you facing any issue or you haven't tried anything?

Comment: Does the XML file *have* to be organized like that? It's not terribly nice to be so order-specific, relying on "the first address element after the name is the address for that name".

Comment: You say C# 3.0 and C# 4.0 and yet you want a Hashtable. Generally speaking, look at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instead. Hashtables and ArrayLists are unofficially obsolete with 2.0+

Comment: In his defense, he might have confused `HashTable` for `HashSet`, which is still in vogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jon Skeet. It would be a better-structured approach to wrap information pertaining to the same person within a single, say, `<Person>` entity. And you should also give some name or ID to each state; otherwise, your groupings appear arbitrary.

```
<states>
  <state Name="Florida">
    <Person Name="a1">
       <Address>a2</Address>
    </Person>
    <Person Name="b1">
       <Address>b2</Address>
    </Person>
    <Person Name="c1">
       <Address>c2</Address>
    </Person>
  </state>
  <state Name="New York">
    <Person Name="aa1">
       <Address>aa2</Address>
    </Person>
    <Person Name="bb1">
       <Address>bb2</Address>
    </Person>
  </state>
</states>
```

Here is how you can construct a two-level dictionary. The outer dictionary is keyed by the state’s name, and valued by a dictionary containing the persons living in that state. The inner dictionary is keyed by the name of the person, and valued by their address.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <states>
      <state Name=""Florida"">
        <Person Name=""a1"">
            <Address>a2</Address>
        </Person>
        <Person Name=""b1"">
            <Address>b2</Address>
        </Person>
        <Person Name=""c1"">
            <Address>c2</Address>
        </Person>
      </state>
      <state Name=""New York"">
        <Person Name=""aa1"">
            <Address>aa2</Address>
        </Person>
        <Person Name=""bb1"">
            <Address>bb2</Address>
        </Person>
      </state>
    </states>");

IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dictionary =                
    document.Root.Elements("state").ToDictionary(
        state => state.Attribute("Name").Value,
        state => state.Elements("Person").ToDictionary(
            person => person.Attribute("Name").Value,
            person => person.Element("Address").Value));

// To get address of "a1" living in Florida:
string addr1 = dictionary["Florida"]["a1"];      // gives "a2"

// To get address of "bb1" living in New York:
string addr2 = dictionary["New York"]["bb1"];    // gives "bb2"
```

Thus, to get the address of person `X` living in city `C`, you just need to access `dictionary[C][X]`.

**Edit**: Reply to comment:

You can change a person’s name by first removing their entry (from the inner dictionary), and then re-adding it (with the new name as the key).

For example, to change the name `"aa1"` to `"aa2"`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> innerDictionary = dictionary["New York"];
string address = innerDictionary["aa1"];
innerDictionary.Remove("aa1");
innerDictionary.Add("xx1", address);
```

That said, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` may not be the best structure if you frequently need to change the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has helped me a lot. I am new to C# so it was a bit problem for me.

Comment: Douglas, that's some really tight code.  Normally I'd just leave everything in the XML document and use XPath with SelectSingleNode( "/states/state[@name='Florida']/person[@name='a1']", but that IDictionary code is a pretty cool way to do it too.

Comment: @Douglas, is there any way to edit the name of some person say aa1 in the dictionary??

Comment: Thanks William! (Although the suggestion was actually Krishh’s.) The dictionary is advantageous if you need to perform a lot of lookups fast. Per MSDN: “Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table.” Krishh: I replied in my post.